# Find the second order differential equation for this RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

How do I obtain the second order linear differential equation in terms of `Vc` in the circuit shown below. I've tried everything I know but still can't get to express `iL` in terms of `Vc`. What else can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCveKV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can see that:

$$0=\text{I}_1\left(t\right)+\text{I}_2\left(t\right)+\text{I}_3\left(t\right)\tag1$$

And for the voltages we can see:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1\left(t\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2'\left(t\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{L}}\\
\\
\text{I}_3\left(t\right)&=\left(\text{V}'\left(t\right)-0\right)\text{C}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}
\tag2
$$

Combinging, gives:

$$0=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}'\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{L}}+\left(\text{V}''\left(t\right)-0\right)\text{C}\tag1$$

Which is easy to solve, because we get:

$$\text{V}\left(t\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle t+\frac{\displaystyle t\sqrt{\text{L}-4\text{CR}^2}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\text{L}}}}{\displaystyle2\text{CR}}\right)\left(\text{k}_1+\text{k}_2\exp\left(\frac{\displaystyle t\sqrt{\text{L}-4\text{CR}^2}}{\displaystyle\text{CR}\sqrt{\text{L}}}\right)\right)\tag4$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I really appreciate it. However, there are two issues I wish to be cleared of. First, I perfectly understand the formula for `I1` and `I3` but that of `I2` is still very much confusing. If `V=L(dI/dt)`, I truly don't know how you got `I=(1/L)*(dV/dt)` without integration. Secondly, the derived equation appears to be a first order differential equation as against the expected second order equation since we ther are two storage elements in the circuit.

Comment: @Jovanny Oh, wait my bad. I'll edit my answer, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Jovanny I edited my answer.